# Get ContentBuilder List View by Ajax Request

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, joomla, joomla-extensions

I'm using Joomla 3 with Crosstec Content Builder Extension and I created a list view for Fron-end users and it's working successfully without any problem:

```
http://epc.aratech.co/index.php/en/?option=com_contentbuilder&view=list&id=6
```

I want to get the extension result via Ajax request without the full website but I'm not able to find the right URL to achieve this behavior.

I tried so many stuff including:

```
http://epc.aratech.co/index.php/en/?option=com_contentbuilder&view=list&id=6&format=raw
http://epc.aratech.co/index.php/en/?option=com_contentbuilder&view=ajax&id=6
```

I hope some can help me.

EDIT:

```
jQuery.ajax({
     type: "GET",
     url: "http://epc.aratech.co/index.php/en/?option=com_contentbuilder&view=list&id=6&format=raw",
     success: function (msg) {
         alert(msg);
     }
 });
```

Comment: can you provide the code for your ajax request?

Comment: I'm using simple ajax request with jQuery

Comment: Yes, I gathered that, but show the code for it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to load only the component's html content add to the URL `tmpl=component`

```
http://epc.aratech.co/index.php/en/?option=com_contentbuilder&view=list&id=6&tmpl=component
```